# Using Environment variables in ElastAlert

Tags: elastalert

I am trying to implement alerts on my data present in elasticsearch using ElastAlert. I would like to know if there is a way to use environment variables or properties file or by exporting the values for changing the fields present in rule types in ElastAlert instead of going and changing the values manually in the rule files to reduce the possibility of an error.

For example, my spike rule configuration looks like this:

```
name: Event spike

type: spike

index: alerting-logs-*

threshold_cur: 300

timeframe:   minutes: 2

spike_height: 2

spike_type: "up"

query_key: HostName

filter:
- query:
    query_string: {query: 'smcfsloglevel:ERROR'}

alert:
- "email"

email:
- "someuser@email.com"
```

Now if I want to change the value of `threshold_cur` from `300` to, say, `500`, can I somehow do it without going to the spike rule file like by exporting like `threshold_cur: ${thr_cur}`

Does anyone have an idea to achieve this?

Comment: A possible alternative is to use https://github.com/andreasjansson/envtpl, which allows you to use jinja2 templating based on environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining threshold_cur in your main elastalert.yml file?

```
current_threshold:300
```

And then in your rule file, reference the threshold_cur value:

```
threshold_cur: {{current_threshold}}
```

I am doing something like this in an alert file that sends an email, and it works.